# Linear maps on irreducible representation of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let G be finite group. Let V be irreducible representation of G over $\mathbb{C}$. For $f\in \mathbb{C}[G]$, consider $\phi_f$ on V, defined by $\phi_f(v) = f.v$ (scaling by f).

I know, $\phi_f$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear. Does the converse true?

If $\phi$ is $\mathbb{C}$- linear on V, does there exist $f\in \mathbb{C}[G]$ such that $\phi=\phi_f$

Please help me with this.

Comment: Are there only finitely many linear maps of $V$?

Comment: As a clarification, is this asking to show that any $\mathbb{C}$ linear map $V\rightarrow V$ is in the image of the map $\mathbb{C}[G]\rightarrow End_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$? For an irreducible representation this is true, but requires a fair bit of theory to have been built up to show.

Comment: No. Even in my question as `$\mathbb(C)[G]$` is infinite, the are infinitely many `$\phi_f$`. @ElliotG

Comment: Yes. @user277182. Can you tell me where to look this?

Comment: This result is sometimes called the Jacobson density theorem, but that's a fair bit more general than this specific case. In this case, this result follows from the decomposition (as $\mathbb{C}$ algebras) of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ into a product of $End_{\mathbb{C}}(V_i)$ for the set of irreps $V_i$. I'll turn this into an answer, since theres a simple proof in this case.

Comment: Sorry; my comment was not useful — ignore.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show for any irrep $V_i$ that the map $\rho:\mathbb{C}[G]\rightarrow End_{\mathbb{C}}(V_i)$ is surjective. We will prove this using some character theory, solets look at the (algebra) product of these maps, over a chosen set of irreducibles $V_i$.

\begin{equation} \mathbb{C}[G]\rightarrow \prod_{V_i} End_{\mathbb{C}}(V_i)\end{equation}

Comparing dimensions, we see that both sides have dimension $|G|$, by the sum of squares of dimensions formula. (This is secretly equivalent to the statement we want to prove, but it definitely seems friendlier).

So to show surjectivity, we just need to show injectivity, since these spaces have the same dimension. So if we had an element $x\in \mathbb{C}[G]$ that acted as zero in every irreducible representation, by linearity, it would act as zero on every representation.

But this cannot occur, as it would contradict the fact that $x$ acts as a nonzero linear transformation on $\mathbb{C}[G]$, viewed as a representation via left multiplication. Thus, the map is injective, hence surjective, giving your result.

Comment: I had partially understood your idea. But I didn't get how did we get contradiction in last step. I didn't get the fact that why x acts as a nonzero linear transformation?

Comment: Also could you please explain how comparing dimension on both sides secretly equivalent to the statement that we want to prove. @user277182

Comment: So $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{C}[G]$, and we have $x\cdot 1=x$, which means that if $x$ isn't zero, then the linear operator "left multiply by $x$" isn't the zero map on this vector space. The idea being, that if $x$ acts as zero on all irreducible representations, then it acts as zero on all representations, and $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is a valid representation for which it doesnt act as zero.

Comment: I view the sum of squares equals $|G|$ claim as secretly equivalent since the proofs I know of this numerical result either rely on the theory of semisimple algebras, or other nontrivial results. Really, to understand the full picture one should forget the fact that $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is a group algebra, and treat it as a semisimple algebra, and use general semisimple algebra theory, as spelled out in Etinghof's Introduction to Representation theory.

Comment: You don't need any deep theory to know that $|G|$ is the sum of the squares of the representation degrees. It follows immedaitely from the inner product of the regular representation with the irreducible representations. So all you need is row orthogonality.

Comment: Making sure I understand this argument, one first establishes complete reducibility, and the character inner product giving the hom space inner product. Then the number of copies of an irrep in the regular rep equals it’s dimension by direct calculation, and every irrep occurs, giving sum of squares formula. That does seem more straightforward!